# Asignar un rol con paquete shinobi Laravel

Tags: laravel

Recibo los siguientes parametros de mi request:

```
"user_email" => "bartell.javon@example.net" "tpaid_id" => "2" "vouche" => "76767" "description" => "Usuarios que tienen disponible la vista de tareas" "status" => "pending" "role_slug" => "deudor"
```

con el siguiente codigo

```
auth()->user()->assignRoles('role-1', 'role-2');
```

Deberia de actualizarme el rol de cualquier usuario que requiera, en mi request puedo regresar el user_id, pero al momento de ejecutar solo se lo aplica a otro usuario que no esta mi request.

Este metodo `(auth()->user()->assignRoles('role-1', 'role-2');)` lo llamo desde mi controlador pago, lo anexo

```
// public function store(Request $request) { // $payment = payment::create($request->all());

    // $roles  = array($request->role_slug);
     //$user = array($request->user_email);
    //  $user = array($request->user_id);
    //  auth()->user()->syncRoles($role->slug);
    // $user =user::first($request->user_id);
     //$user = auth()->user()->assignRoles( '$user', '20');


        //dd($request->all());

    // return redirect()->route('payments.edit' , $payment->id)
               //  ->with('info', 'Pago Registrado con Exito');

}
```

me pueden ayudar?

Comment: Si lo que quieres es asignarle un rol específico a un usuario, basta con encontrar ese usuario con `find()` y luego `$user->assignRole()`. No veo que uses `find()` en ningún momento.

Comment: Correcto, solventado. Agradecido!!